# Proprietary Web Components

Tags: javascript, web-component

Let's say we have some proprietary web components which were designed and developed for a specific company needs.

**Can we safeguard our web components from being used by others?** If yes, how?

**Note:** I am not talking about other developers modifying the component, I am only thinking about others using them straight away in the first place.

Comment: Nothing can stop `Ctrl`+`c` and `Ctrl`+`v` when viewing the page source. The best you can do is obfuscate it, but it can always be deobfuscated .

Comment: Web Components don’t change anything about how this has always worked for JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

It is just JS. All you can do is delay hackers.

The most you can do is use tools like JSObfuscator and JSFuck to make your code as unreadable as possible. But ofcourse experienced hackers have tools also...

Then it dawned me; it is all about adding extra hurdles, and there is one more hurdle we can call to action.

[I wrote a nerdy DEV.to blog post about using the URI to encode your Web Components](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/protecting-your-web-components-but-you-did-not-hear-this-from-me-3b59)

Basically boils down to NOT putting the Dictionary in the file itself, like Obfuscators do;
but placing the encoding dictionary in the URI (Domain Path even better!):

```
<script src="element.js?-customElements-define-HTMLElement-"></script>
```

And executing:

```
let D = document.currentScript.src.split`-`;

// D = ["element.js?","customElements","define","HTMLElement"];

window[D[1]][D[2]]("my-element",class extends window[D[3]]{ ... });
```